# substitute with SED recursively

Tags: debian, sed, grep, recursive

Is it possible to substitute a sample recursively in multi directory with grep and sed like that ?

```
grep -e "http://localhost:4000" -r ~/dev_web/_site  | sed -e 's/http:\/\/localhost:4000/https:\/\/another_site.com/g'
```

When I do that, my terminal show me that is done, but when I do again a grep:

```
grep -e "https://another_site.com" -r ~/dev_web/_site
```

it show me only 4 files changed..

And if I do :

```
 grep -e "http://localhost:4000" -r ~/dev_web/_site/
```

the sample http:localhost:4000 is still here

Answer (score 4):

Your pipeline changes no files.  It pulls out lines that matches the regular expression using `grep`, then changes that data, but does not attempt to make changes in any files.

Instead, assuming GNU `sed`:

```
find ~/dev_web/_site -type f \
    -exec grep -qF 'http://localhost:4000' {} ';' \
    -exec sed -i 's#http://localhost:4000#https://another.site#g' {} +
```

This would find all regular files in or under the directory `~/dev_web/_site`.  For each such file, `grep` first tests whether the file contains the given string.  If it does, GNU `sed` is invoked to make an in-place substitution.

The `grep` step could be omitted, but GNU `sed` would update the modification timestamp on *all* files without it.

You may want to only look in a subset of the files in the directories beneath `~/dev_web/_site`. If this is the case, restrict the search with  something like `-name '*.js'` (or whatever name pattern you want to match) just after `-type f`.

Adding `-print` just before `-exec sed ...` would print the pathnames of the files that `find` would give to `sed`.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Answer (score 1):

your sed session worked on grep's output, not actual file.

use `grep` to list file (*)

```
grep -e "http://localhost:4000" -r ~/dev_web/_site -l
```

then use `xargs` and `sed -i` to edit in place

```
xargs sed -i -e 's;http://localhost:4000;https://another_site.com;g'
```

(on a side note you can change delimiter in sed)

Now all together

```
grep -e "http://localhost:4000" -r ~/dev_web/_site -l |
xargs sed -i -e 's;http://localhost:4000;https://another_site.com;g'
```

This can be one-lined of course, note that pipe symbol (`|`) can be use a line continuation.

(*) I assume file don't have space, new line and other funny char in their names.

Comment: Thanks l didn't saw your answer yet

Answer (score 1):

Your first grep extract lines from files, not **list** files.
To obtain a list of files matched use the `-l` option to grep:

```
$ grep -rl "htt...."  ~/dir
```

To execute the modification of files with sed, give the list to sed (invert the order):

```
$ sed -e 's#http://localhost:4000#https://another_site.com#g' \
$(grep -rle "http://localhost:4000" ~/dev_web/_site)
```

That assume "clean" filenames: No spaces or new lines.

A more robust option is to use find:

```
fromname='http://localhost:4000
toname='https://another_site.com'
searchdir=~/dev_web/_site
find "$searchdir" -type f \
    -exec grep -qF "$fromname" {} ';' \
    -exec sed -i 's#'"$fromname"'#'"$toname"'#g' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

The best for me is with a for :

```
for i in $(grep -R "string_to_change" | awk -F: '{print $1}');do sed -i 's/string_to_change/string_changed/g' $i ;done
```

The explanation: with grep -R lookfor the string recursively, always put the name with a : before, so you have the hole path of the file. And finally do the sed to the file extracted.

Regards